# Are there any non-responsive CSS frameworks around? if so, please list them

Tags: css, frameworks, responsive-design

I developed a website for a client using a responsive framework and we found that they don't like it changing when the device is small, they want the website to look the same when on a IPhone as it does on a Windows PC. Since I'm using Zurb Foundation CSS I found its very difficult to make it non-responsive.

What other CSS frameworks exist which can allow for a fixed layout now? I see most of the frameworks say responsive now.

Comment: how about not using framework and develop your own CSS scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use twitter bootstrap and just not include (exclude) the responsive CSS file that comes in the package inside css folder.
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2):

There are many CSS frameworks around. You can pick fixed layout frameworks such as [960 Grid](http://960.gs) to use if you intend not to support responsive design.

Reference: [Wikipedia for CSS Frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_frameworks)

Comment: Ok it seems a few of the ones listed there can be fixed. The problem with Zurb Foundation CSS is that it cannot, at this moment, be used easily as a fixed CSS framework.